# How do I select emails from list to send

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a user's role table called lookup_roles and it contain user_id, email, and role fields.

I need to pull the emails of the rows that have a 'S' (S stands for test in this system) in the role field and put them into the $to for the else statement below to be emailed.

```
    if ($production == 'Y' ) {

 $subject = "Production Subject";
 $to      = 'prodemail@email.com' . ', ';

} else {

 $subject = "[TEST]";
 $to      = 'testemai1@email.com' . ', ';
 $to     .= 'testemail2@email.com ' . ', ';
```

I have a feeling it's pretty simple.  Appreciate the help.  I'm still a noob at this.

Comment: SELECT * FROM lookup_roles WHERE role_fiels = 'S'

Comment: Thanks Marco, but how do I add the results to the $to variable?

Comment: loop the only result you got and do a $to .= $row['email'] (you can loop with mysqli_fetch_array (Example), pdo, deprecated mysql_* =) it depends on the command you use for the query itself

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email FROM lookup_roles WHERE role LIKE 'S'
```

And then simply walk through the results and put them to the $to variable.

Comment: Ok, so how do I put that to the $to variables?  I think that's what I really need help with.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems you haven't even done a MySQl query within php. So for that you should take a look into the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIKE operator of MySql.

```
$what_type = "test";  
$sql = "SELECT email from lookup_roles where email like '%" . $what_type . "%'";
```

I didn't test it yet.